# ImageMagick requirement for Paperclip plugin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, installation, imagemagick, paperclip

The paperclip plugin says that I need to install ImageMagick in order to use Paperclip. I'm typically really bad at getting things installed and running, so I was wondering if anyone could explain to me the exact specific steps I should take to get it installed and communicating with Paperclip.

Comment: Ask on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: And tell them what platform you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link that [discusses downloading ImageMagick.](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=9sonkfolbtqvafmpc5b9v8fdm7)

As you can see, it is a bit different depending on your environment your using, but generally you either install it via a package manager or via source.

Comment: thanks, but I was more looking for specific instructions. I downloaded ImageMagick and extracted its contents... but I'm kinda stuck from here... the instructions in the link you provided doesn't really work for me